# Horizontal Menu Getting Cutoff

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, horizontallist

I'm working on a glitch on a client's site that I didn't design. The horizontal submenu gets cutoff at the largest width. How can I make the submenu item centered on the screen? 
Here's the link: http://joannaintarazim.org/new/

I've been working on this for hours and I can't seem to figure it out...
Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean by "cut off"? I see the whole menu, but as drop down with a smaller screen, and as a sub horizontal menu by full width.

Comment: if you resize without refreshing, it gets cut off.

Comment: I actually need to make it centered on the screen (I forgot to add that in my question).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you answer:

Put this into your CSS:

```
@media (min-width:1270px) {
    #menu-item-35 ul.sub-menu {
    left: -340px !important;
    }
}
```

[image]

This will NOT center the horizontal, but will work well from 1270 px screen width and up (where the UL  list is displayed horizontal)